# Should I use a cronjob or write the script in php?

Tags: php

So I am developing a PHP app that loops through a list of websites stored in the database, downloads their RSS feeds and checks if there are any new posts. If yes, It inserts these posts into the database and displays them on the index page.

My code for the database loop is on the head of the index.php so that everytime you open the app, it does what is said above and then displays the fresh results after it finishes.

But I have noticed that it can take some time to do so every time you refresh the page. Do you think I should use a cronjob for it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a look at [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you must use CRON job which runs once a day and fetch the latest data. Because the way you are using makes your page very very slow to open because at the start it will first check all the websites then store in the database this will make your page visitors annoyed and want them to leave. So rather then using this way please use CRON job which will run separately and doesn't make your site slow. Also i will recommend you to use stored procedures to save the data in database in order to save the script execution time. Hope my suggestion will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use a cronjob.

> use a cronjob or write the script in php?

To make it clear a cronjob is just executing something on a schedule. It doesn't change how to write it. You can still write the cron in php, it will just be executed in a different way.

```
0    *     *     *     *     /usr/bin/php /path/to/pull_rss_feeds.php
```